# how avoid set a global variable in recursive class

Tags: java

I have a global variable in a recursive class, each time I call it, the variables are created. The variable at begin is: int count = 0, then in the method I increase: count ++, the problem is when call again the class, the variable is reset to zero. I need the variable "count" remains in 1,  to again increase in each call to 2,3,4.... etc

I try with this: `private static int count = 0;` but not work..

Comment: Can you post the code to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the code for all references to your `count` variable. Most likely, you are re-setting to 0 somehow. For example:

```
private class MyClass {

    private static int count = 0;

    public MyClass() {
        count = 0; //Bad line
    }

    public void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }

}
```

If you have something like that, then every time you create a new `MyClass` object, you would be resetting `count` to 0 **for all MyClass objects**.

But you really need to add your class code to your question. Otherwise we can't help.